# How to search through online сhеss games using AppleScript or Automator?

Tags: applescript, automator

I would like to search for specific online сhеss games. Each game has a single adress. Since there are millions of games on instant chess, it would take far too long to index all the games. So I will set a limit and use the script at night. Conditions should be something like this:

http://www.instantchess.com/?EXP=1&GPI=84094532

To start, could the script search games 84094532 to 84095000 and store the web addresses of all the games with Reti opening in them so I could see the games by myself during the day?

Comment: It will be a bit hard for anyone to point you in the right direction without any more information on the site than "specific online сhеss games"

Comment: If you want to do web crawling, I would suggest language like Python.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Let's say instantchess.com. Here's a game url: http://www.instantchess.com/?EXP=1&GPI=84094532 84094532 is the game id. Let's say I want to search every Reti openings (thus the page must contain the word "Reti") from id 84000000 to 85000000. How can I do it? I think it should be pretty simple. Matthieu Riegle gave me the idea there should already be programs doing web crawling. I will try to find one. If anyone has suggestions to point me in the right direction, feel free.

Comment: As asked this question doesn't really fit into the Q&A format used on this site. It sounds like an interesting programming challenge though, people usually tackle this by breaking the problem down into smaller steps (how do get a chess game from the site, how to store it locally, how to compare two games, what to do with the result etc.). The fun starts when you try to solve these problems on your own. If you run into problems with one of the steps, feel free to come back and ask specific questions either here or (if outside of AD scope) on stackoverflow.com.

Comment: I will edit in the URL you answered, but I'll need you to explain what the script will do - are you hoping to have pages downloaded to your desktop? a list of URL that you can click? What is to be done with each web page?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for trying to help me but someone has already done it. This question can be marked as solved. Here is his script (all credit goes to him):

```
set retiList to {}
set theStart to 84094500    
set theEnd to 84094600   
repeat with gameRef from theStart to theEnd    
  set theScript to ("curl 'http://www.instantchess.com/?EXP=1&GPI=" & gameRef as string) & "'"
  set theSource to do shell script theScript
  if theSource contains "reti" then
   set end of retiList to gameRef
  end if
end repeat
retiList
```

Comment: Awesome! We can't mark it solved, but you can after a short delay. Thanks so much for documenting this.